# Django Rest Framework and @staticmethod. What is the benefit of it?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, static-methods

I was coding some methods in serializers.py usign PyCharm. Then I had to code a method to get a name.

```
 def get_artist_name(obj):
    return obj.artist.name
```

Then PyCharm suggested me to make the method static.

```
 @staticmethod
 def get_artist_name(obj):
    return obj.artist.name
```

Since then I'm wondering what is benefit of it? It's a good practice or something like that? If there is any documentation I can read about this specific topic, thanks in advance.

Comment: If you do not make it static, then the `obj` will take the `self` parameter (the serializer with which you call it).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The first variant is wrong: if you call an *instance* method, the first parameter is the *callee* (the `x` in `x.method(para, meter)`). So that would mean here that you need to write it like:

```
def get_artist_name(self, obj):
    return obj.artist.name
```

To let it work properly, as is demonstrated in the [documentation of a **`SerializerMethodField`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield).

Since however you do not *use* the `self` in your function body, there is no use to write a function with the `self` parameter. Furthermore by not making it a `@staticmethod`, the function can only be called properly with a serializer instance: if you would call it with `SerializerClass.get_artist_name(None, obj)`, then you need to provide a first parameter that is not used. This in contrast to calling it with `some_serializer.get_artist_name(obj)`, where there is only one *explicit* parameter.

By using `@staticmethod`, you "harmonize" the two: now you can call `SerializerClass.get_artist_name(obj)`, and `some_serializer.get_artist_name(obj)`, and thee `@staticmethod` decorator, will ensure that both work the same way.

Unless you think you will need access to the serializer object, or the subclasses will need that (well typically you want to avoid "removing" decorators from subimplementations), it is probably more elegant to use the `@staticmethod`.